# android leanback search fragment

Tags: android-tv, leanback, google-voice-search

I am using Android `Search Fragment` in `Android TV` app.There is a specific requirement where on focus on voice search icon I want the color to become blue not just scale .Sharing the snapshot of present behavior[image].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to do whole background blue while focus on voice search ?

Comment: Only the voice search icon to become blue.

Comment: you can set the colors by using `setSearchAffordanceColors()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unsupported hack, but it'll get the job done. You can override the color `lb_speech_orb_recording` as a color in your `colors.xml` file in your project. Then it looks like the below image:

[image]